# choosing a loss function for gbm

Tags: r, loss-functions, boosting

I am using `gbm` to predict an imbalanced binary outcome, with the intent of obtaining a ranking by class probability estimation that produces a strong class separation on out-of-sample data.  (I am combining this class probability with other predictions, including from logistic regression, in an ensemble model.)

According to [this gbm vignette](http://bioconductor.wustl.edu/extra/vignettes/gbm/inst/doc/gbm.pdf) (Ridgeway, 2007), under "common user options" for loss functions:

> This should be easily dictated by the application.  For most
>   classification problems either `bernoulli` or `adaboost` will be
>   appropriate, the former being recommended. (p. 5)

There's no explanation provided for favoring bernoulli over [adaboost](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/37497/how-to-use-r-gbm-with-distribution-adaboost) nor any mention of the option for [`huberized` loss function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huber_loss), although this function may have been added at a later date.

Related question, but broader than mine:  [Choosing between loss functions for binary classification](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/112359/choosing-between-loss-functions-for-binary-classification).  This answer references [Bartlett (2006)](http://www.eecs.berkeley.edu/~wainwrig/stat241b/bartlettetal.pdf) which is a challenging read for me.

Although performance is satisfactory under the bernoulli loss function, I am having a hard time understanding the justification for selecting one over another.  I'm trying all of them, but are there any theoretical justifications that are at least somewhat intuitive?